# Android TableRow positioning

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to make a kind of weapon selector for my game. It will consisted of a left arrow, the weapon image, and a right arrow.

My approach is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/larrow"
        android:id="@+id/img_larrow" />
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ak47"
        android:id="@+id/img_ak47" />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/rarrow"
        android:id="@+id/img_rarrow" />
</TableRow>
```

The problem is, I want to make it position on the bottom-center. So far I just can make it position on the bottom or top center via the TableRow's android:gravity attribute. There is "bottom" and "center_horizontal" attribute for android:gravity but none for bottom center. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When you will check both "bottom" and "center_horizontal" it will become `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to combine the 2 like this `android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`